# UDF Data value changes after saving the file as a csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I've generated a random **userId** using **UDF** and assigned it to the table with withColumn

after **df.show()** this is the table:

| userID | name |
| --- | --- |
| bdjq7vn3 | Jhon |
| 8br64v24 | Ronan |

however when i write the newly created df to my local computer as a csv file, the userID is changeD

local csv table:

| userID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3r8fmkt1 | Jhon |
| fmwxgc28 | Ronan |

**what sorcery is this?**

Comment: Can you provide some code? I believe that might be related with evaluation order.

Comment: Unless you cache the dataframe and the cache can stay in memory, every time you run action functions, spark will rerun the plan.  So if your udf is generating random string without `state` or some sort, you will get new one every time you run action functions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this inconsistency is like [Emma's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770491/udf-data-value-changes-after-saving-the-file-as-a-csv#comment126835529_71770491), `show` and `save` are two actions and your UDF would be called twice, hence two different random IDs.

If random user ID is your requirement, then you would want to generate it once (using either your UDF or [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) or [`rand`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.rand)), then **save** it. Your ID would be permanently stored and won't change anymore.

Comment: each time I call the df.show() changes the userID, how can the data change again and again as i didnot call the withColoumn udf cell?

Comment: if you don't cache or save to store anything, every single time you trigger `df.show()`, all transformation from very beginning (including `withColumn` udf cell) will be computed.

Comment: [image](https://postimg.cc/4HYGhF5f)  I tried to store it in a different variable but the result is changed. is there any procedure to save the exact file generated from the first process?

Comment: you ran `toPandas` twice, therefore `lonlat` udf run twice, that's why you have two different latlon for each employee. Change the first `toPandas` to `save` (as CSV for example), then read from that CSV, you will have a persistence latlon

Comment: [notWorking](https://postimg.cc/BjPxCxpM),save and show are two different actions emma said?

Comment: [didn't-even-call-show-twice](https://postimg.cc/VJHzztcQ) what is going on here

Comment: it **is** working, you can simply ignore the output of command #87 (it is only for debugging purpose). Keep reading from csv, you'll have consistence lon value

Comment: just **save once** and **read from it twice**. **DON'T save twice**

Comment: @pltc is right.  `toPandas`, `show`, `count`, `write` and many others https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions are all actions.  Whenever you **see** data is usually you are calling an action function. In your screenshot, you call `toPandas()` then you call `write` => calling action functions twice.